# Function type parameter in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

For some reason Doxygen doesn't seem to correctly display the parameter if it has a function type:

```
/// Brief...
/// 
/// Details...
void x(int f(int, int));
```

In the list of functions, it shows correctly, but in the detailed entry for `x`, the parameter `f` is displayed as:

```
int fint, int
```

instead.  Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: Just a guess, but try an explicit function pointer.

Comment: Not really an option here though since it's not really my code, so I need to keep the ABI the same.

Comment: Your function is already taking a function pointer as its parameter. The compiler interprets a function as a function pointer, just like it interprets an array like a pointer.

Comment: That does make sense.  Is it guaranteed by the standard?  Just curious.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding either, but yes. I would imagine the function one is right next to the array one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not primarily a Doxygen problem. Your declaration is not so nice as used in the source, I'd prefer a `typedef`:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
/**
 * Type alias \c F for function signature: \code int (*)(int, int) \endcode
 */
typedef int (*F)(int, int);
```

and the function declaration

```
/**
 * Function using \em fnPtr with function pointer alias signature 
 * \c MyNamespace::F.
 * @param fnPtr A callback function pointer with alias signature 
 *              \c MyNamespace::F.
 */
void x(F fnPtr);
} // close MyNamespace scope
```

The generated Doxygen documentation will look proper accordingly IMHO:

[image: Generated Documentation Screenshot]

Comment: @Fylwind Please note that it's **not only** a workaround to get doxygen right, but enhances usability of your API a lot, since clients simply can refer to the `typedef` instead of having to retype the function signature.

Comment: I would never use a raw function (pointer) type in my own (C++) code though.